# Add a Spritefont in monogame

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, monogame

I am currently using monogame 3.4 and Visual Studio 2013.

I was trying to do a personal project, a minigame, and I need to have some text in the screen. I found that I need right click the content folder, add a new Item, select spritefont, but I dont have that content file.

I read somewhere that this is only possible to do in Visual Studio 2010.

Is that true? If not, how do I add text in the screen?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you're asking about adding spritefont file and your VS doesn't have a template, spritefont file is just an XML file. You can create XML file and rename it to abc.spritefont and copy it's content from some samples.

Comment: @Alkasai, I tried that, but I have the following error: "Could not load <font directory> asset as non content file".

Comment: you'll have to specify content processor in the file properties. at least that's how it used to be in XNA. don't think it's much different in the MonoGame. just look at a MonoGame sample and make sure that all the properties are set the same way for a spritefont.